# DTO DAO POCO BO

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, design-patterns

Actually i'm pretty confused about this terms and how they relate to each other. A read something about every one of them but i don't uderstant the work flow..

DTO - Data transfer object - object to transport values
BO Business object - object in domain model. object to make Business logic with
POCO - no idea, i've read a definition on wiki but didn't understood anything
DAO - data access object - object to map the DB table ?

Could someone please bring some light into it for me ?

Comment: best. title. ever. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- **DTO**: Data Transfer Object, used to transfer data between loosly coupled services
- **POCO**: Plain Old Clr Object, normal CLR object doesn't use any attributes or required inheritance to act as a DAO/DTO
- **BO**: Business Object, contains business logic, used in the Business Logic part of your solution
- **DAO**: Data Access Object, used to transfer data from your database

So a regular workflow would be to request data from a service, which is sent to your app as a DTO, you convert it to a BO to manipulate it and send it back as a DTO or after converting it to a DAO store it in a database.

You use the different object to separate concerns between the 3 types, a BO doesn't need to know whether it's persisted using a database or a service.

Comment: Well said.  Brief, but effective.

Comment: The only thing what I miss, is what to do, if you BO logic needs to load data? How can it access the DAO?

Comment: @pihentagy that's what dal does.

Comment: just as an addition: you could think of DAO as DTO between BO and database

Answer (score 3):

Timeline based scaffolding:

- Batch => Stored Procedure => "plain old clr object" => npmagenda
- Socket => ODBC => "data access object" => NoSQL
- CSV => XML => "data transfer object" => JSON
- FTP => CGI => "business object" => AJAX

**References**

- [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698)
- [npmjs: agenda - Light weight job scheduler for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda)
- [Corba, XML and ODBC](http://www.arcavia.com/kyle/Rants/XML%20Sucks.html)
- [webdav by hand](http://uwiki.org/uwiki/curl_dav.html)
- [Export MVC WebGrid to Excel (CSV)](http://blogs.askcts.com/2012/12/06/export-mvc-webgrid-to-excel-csv/)
- [Stored Procedure POCO Generator Utility for SQL Server](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1683/stored-procedure-poco-generator-utility-for-sql-server.aspx)
- [Technical Standard Systems Management: Data Storage Management (XDSM) API (pdf)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9695979099/toc.pdf)
- [JVM to .Net Interop](https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/may-2014-jvm-to-net-interop/)